# Bitbake "addtask deploy after do_install" not working from image recipe

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have some recipes which add a 'deploy' task after install using "addtask deploy after do_install"

This always worked as expected, however after an update to Poky Kirkstone, the behaviour seems changed.

Observed behaviour:

- When executing 'bitbake recipe-name' both do-install and do_deploy are executed.
- When the recipe is built via the image recipe, do_install is executed, however do_deploy is not.

Peforming a 'bitbake -c clean recipe-name' before the image build has no effect.

When I check the log directory for the recipe (which contains symlinks to the latest log file), the symlink to run.do_deploy is not updated either (when building the image). In case only the recipe is built, the do_deploy symlink is updated. So the task is really not executed when building via the image recipe.

Somebody has a clue what might be wrong here ?

Comment: did you try to use "inherit deploy" ?

Comment: "inherit deploy" is present. I added it after I encountered  this issue, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: add this at the end of your .bb file :

addtask do_deploy after do_compile before do_build.

You should also make sure to inherit deploy and nopackages

Comment: No clue, but I noticed the same behavior. If someone knows the reason, I’d be glad to hear it.